# Shape of the space of diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D_n$ be the set of real $n \times n$ matrices that are diagonalizable over the real numbers.  I know that these are exactly the matrices that are diagonalizable over the complex numbers and such that the eigenvalues are real, and I know various sufficient conditions for this to hold (e.g., if a matrix is symmetric or all the eigenvalues are real and distinct).

How should I mentally picture $D_n$?  Is this set connected (or how many components are there)? Closed?

For example, I picture $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$  as the complement of the variety given by the determinant.  This tells me for example that such matrices are dense in the space of all $n \times n$ real matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that $D_n$ is path-connected. Indeed, it is even star-shaped : for every $A \in D_n$, the path $t \mapsto tA$ joins $A$ to the zero matrix in $D_n$, and hence every $A \in D_n$ can be joined to the zero matrix by a path in $D_n$.

$D_n$ is not closed : one can prove that the closure of $D_n$ is the set of matrices that are similar to a triangular matrix.

$D_n$ is not open either : one can prove the the interior of $D_n$ is the set of matrices that have $n$ distincts eigenvalues.

Note that if you work over $\mathbb{C}$, these results are still true, but since every matrix is similar to a triangular one over $\mathbb{C}$, you get that diagonalizable matrices are dense in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (which is maybe easier to picture).

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful explanation!

Comment: @Sprotte You are welcome !